# Symfony2 - Need help on how to join ManyToMany relationship into a query

Tags: symfony, tags, blogs, entity-relationship

I'm currently using a createQueryBuilder to join 2 entities (category and blog) that are One ToMany and ManyToOne.

I've recently added a tag entity to blog (ManyToMany/ManyToMany) and would like to join this in the same query.

How would I do this?

current query:

```
public function getBlogs($limit = null)
{
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('b')
        ->select('b, c')
        ->leftJoin('b.category', 'c')
        ->addOrderBy('b.created', 'DESC');

    return $qb->getQuery()
        ->getResult();
}
```

tag entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Blog", mappedBy="tags")
 */
protected $blogs;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->blogs = new ArrayCollection();
}
```

blog entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Category", inversedBy="blogs")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="category_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
protected $category;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Tag", inversedBy="blogs")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="tag_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
protected $tags;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->tags = new ArrayCollection();
}
```

category entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Blog", mappedBy="category")
 */
protected $blogs;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->blogs = new ArrayCollection();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be pretty easy by doing the following:

```
public function getBlogs($limit = null)
{
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('b')
        ->select('b, c, tag')
        ->leftJoin('b.category', 'c')
        ->leftJoin('b.tags', 'tag')
        ->addOrderBy('b.created', 'DESC')
    ;

    // ...
}
```

Comment: I was using that same query for joining category and blog, see updated question. How can set it up to include the tag entity as well?

Comment: So this shouldn't be a problem for tags as well. I updated my answer according to your latest changes.

Comment: Worked! Thanks Michael. Question for you, what is the difference between a leftJoin and a innerJoin? I couldn't find any documentation that explained this.

Comment: You're welcome.
This is more a SGBD question you're asking now. With inner joins, only blog posts that do have a category and at least one tag will be returned, while with left joins all blog posts will be returned, even if they don't have any category or associated tag. I would probably use an innerJoin for categories (a blog post *must* have a category) but leftJoin for tags (blog posts may not have tags).

Comment: I see. Again Michael, thank you for explaining and sharing you knowledge with me. Greatly appreciated.